# Django's login_required decorator does not redirect to previous page

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-templates, django-views

My problem in the short version:

I have added the `login_required` decorator to one of my views. If I enter the URL in the browser which executes this view, the browser correctly redirects to the URL that contains my login form if the user is not authenticated. However, the browser never redirects back to the previous page and I have no idea why this does not work. I have tried hundreds of things.

My problem in the long version:

I have a Django project with a single app, let's call it `my_app`. All the templates of my project reside in `templates/my_app/`. I have a template called `main.html` which contains several forms, among them my login form. With an additional `POST` parameter called `form-type`, I check which of the forms has been submitted. The code looks like this:

```
def process_main_page_forms(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['form-type'] == u'login-form':
            template_context = _log_user_in(request)

        elif request.POST['form-type'] == u'registration-form':
            template_context = _register_user(request)

        elif request.POST['form-type'] == u'password-recovery-form':
            template_context = _recover_password(request)

    else:
        template_context = {
            'auth_form': AuthenticationForm(),
            'registration_form': RegistrationForm(),
            'password_recovery_form': EmailBaseForm()
        }

    return render(request, 'my_app/main.html', template_context)
```

The function `_log_user_in()` looks like this:

```
def _log_user_in(request):

    message = ''
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
        else:
            message = 'Your account has been disabled. ' \
                      'Please contact the administrator.'
    else:
        message = 'Your username and password didn\'t match. Please try again.'

    template_context = {
        'auth_form': AuthenticationForm(),
        'registration_form': RegistrationForm(),
        'password_recovery_form': EmailBaseForm(),
        'message': message,
}

    return template_context
```

I also include the necessary `<input>` elements in the template, e.g. for the login form this is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-type" value="login-form" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

The URL pattern for this view is:

```
url(r'^$', process_main_page_forms, name='main-page')
```

My second view renders two forms for changing email address and password for an authenticated user. It looks like this:

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def change_user_credentials(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.POST['form-type'] == u'change-email-form':
            template_context = _change_email_address(request)

        elif request.POST['form-type'] == u'change-password-form':
            template_context = _change_password(request)

    else:
        template_context = {'change_email_form': ChangeEmailForm()}

    return render(request, 'my_app/user.html', template_context)
```

The URL pattern for this second view is:

```
url(r'^account/$', change_user_credentials, name='user-page')
```

Whenever I access `/account/` when I'm not authenticated, I'm successfully redirected to the main page that contains the login form. The resulting URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?next=/account/` that contains the necessary `next` parameter. However, when I log in my account, I'm still on the main page. I never get redirected to the user page, although I provided the necessary `next` parameter in the login form. It seems that this parameter is always empty, but I don't know why. I also don't have any other redirection calls in my code.

Can you help me solving this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Side-note: you seem to be using forms in a really odd way; instead of getting `username` and `password` directly from `request.POST`, use `request.POST` when instantiating a form, *i.e.* `form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)` then test on `form.is_valid()`. This way you get validation (and some sanitization), and you don't need `form-type` at all. It'd also solve the current bug in your code whereby the entered username isn't remembered if the password is wrong.

Comment: See the [Working with Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) documentation for more.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a trite answer, but the reason that no redirect is happening is because you don't seem to be doing anything with the `next` query parameter.

In fact, in the event that a user logs in successfully, you show the same page (albeit with a different context dictionary) as if they attempted to do something else:

```
def process_main_page_forms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['form-type'] == u'login-form':
            template_context = _log_user_in(request)

        ...
    ...

    return render(request, 'my_app/main.html', template_context)
```

As the [Django docs explain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login), it's the `contrib.auth.views.login()` function that processes the `next` parameter, and you're not using that view (although you are using the confusingly-identically-named [`contrib.auth.login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) *function*).

You should either just use the included view (which, in addition to processing `next`, also checks for `is_active`), or add the redirect functionality to your view, in which case it's probably worth bringing the authentication code into `process_main_page_forms()` unless you're sure you'll need `_log_user_in()` elsewhere:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings

def process_main_page_forms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['form-type'] == u'login-form':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    if request.GET.get('next', False):
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))
                    else:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
                else:
                    message = 'Your account has been disabled.'
            else:
                message = 'Your username and password didn\'t match. Please try again.'

            # If we've reached this point then the login failed
            template_context = {
                'auth_form': AuthenticationForm(),
                'registration_form': RegistrationForm(),
                'password_recovery_form': EmailBaseForm(),
                'message': message,
            }
        elif ...:
            # Do things with other form types
    else:

    return render(request, 'my_app/main.html', template_context)
```

The [example usage of `contrib.auth.login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) has the following:

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

Your code is almost there, but you were missing the "redirect to a success page" part, which is where `next` would come into play.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. Indeed, I've messed up the login view and the login function. I have included your proposed `HttpResponseRedirect` calls in my code in exactly the same way you did it in your example, but it does not have any effect. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Just a small addition. I've read about the login view, but as far as I understand, one needs a separate URL pattern for this view to work correctly. However, I have to include all three forms on the same page as mentioned above because this is a requirement by my customer. Any other idea?

Comment: Puzzling. You could try some of [Simon Willison's Django debugging techniques](http://simonwillison.net/2008/May/22/debugging/) to find out why you're not hitting `return` statements (which should obviously prevent the rest of your function, including `render`, from executing. Either `print` statements or `raise` will give you an idea of what's going wrong with control flow, but definitely spend a few minutes learning `pdb` if you need to go deeper into the issue.

Comment: I can't see a path in my suggested code where a user could be logged in but not redirected. Perhaps you could [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) your whole `views.py` file? It's possible an indentation problem is causing an `else` to be associated with the wrong `if` or similar.

Comment: And finally, you can call views from other views — you'd just do `from django.contrib.auth.views import login; return login(request)` within your view. Even if this weren't possible, an alternative would be to submit the login form to a dedicated URL using (hooked up to `auth.views.login`) using AJAX.